# password hashing cannot login codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, bcrypt

I have this helper to encrpyt my password

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
 * This function used to generate the hashed password
 * @param {string} $plainPassword : This is plain text password
 */
if(!function_exists('getHashedPassword'))
{
    function getHashedPassword($plainPassword)
    {
        return password_hash($plainPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
}
/**
 * This function used to generate the hashed password
 * @param {string} $plainPassword : This is plain text password
 * @param {string} $hashedPassword : This is hashed password
 */
if(!function_exists('verifyHashedPassword'))
{
    function verifyHashedPassword($plainPassword, $hashedPassword)
    {
        return password_verify($plainPassword, $hashedPassword) ? true : false;
    }
}

?>
```

Now I don't have any problem storing the hashed password to my database and I am doing it like this

on my `model`

```
function saveAccount($userinfo)
{
    $data = array(
       'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
       'password' => $userinfo,
       'type' => $this->input->post('accountType')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('users', $data);

}
```

and on my `controller`

```
$userInfo = getHashedPassword($this->input->post('password'));
$this->employee->saveAccount($userInfo);
```

Now this registration process is currently working and I don't have any problem storing it on my database now my problem is that whenever I tried to login to the user i currently registered for like example .
username : `admin5`
password : `admin5` (which is encrypted on my database)

on my controller for logging in

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');  
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$user_data = $this->employee->can_login($username,$password);
```

and on my model

```
function can_login($username, $password)
    {

        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $user = $query->result();

        verifyHashedPassword($password, $user[0]->password);
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->row_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

what do you think could be the problem ?

Comment: You're calling `verifyHashedPassword()`, but you're completely ignoring the functions response. Currently, that function call is completely pointless.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson how did I ignore the response sir? sorry

Comment: You're ignoring the response since you're not storing, using or checking the response in any way shape or form. If you would remove that call, nothing in your code would change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this a tad overly complex - the actions of the functions you are using makes little sense to put inside a function - its a simple one-liner. And `password_verify()` already returns a boolean `true`/`false`, so you don't need to use a ternary operator either.

Your insert can be more clear and explicit by doing the following (and removing your `getHashedPassword()` function),

```
function saveAccount()
{
    $data = array(
       'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
       'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
       'type' => $this->input->post('accountType')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
```

Then in your `can_login()` function, you cannot query the password in a `WHERE` clause. By doing that, you will never get a result back (as the hash isn't comparable through a comparison operator). You need to fetch it, and then compare the retrieved hash by using `password_verify()`. Calling your `verifyHashedPassword()` without checking the result won't magically check anything. Now, you can also remove your `verifyHashedPassword()` function.

```php
function can_login($username, $password) {
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $user = $query->result();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 && password_verify($password, $user[0]->password)) {
        return $query->row_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your `password` column should be of at least 60 characters length, although to accommodate future changes, it can be longer (for example 255 characters long).

Comment: Thank you and sorry for making it complex